# Get half of every neibours bytes in python

Tags: python, byte

I have this bytes object:

```
test = b"\x05\x08\x06\x04\x01\x05"
```

and would like to get this from it, building bytes in the output with halves of the two neigbour bytes:

```
result = b"\x50\x80\x60\x40\x10"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a very little bit of math: you can get the last four bits of your byte with `b % 16`, and the first four with integer division by 16. Then you just have to combine both parts.

Note that you get integers when indexing/iterating on a bytes object.

So:

```
test=b"\x05\x08\x06\x04\x01\x05" 
result=b"\x50\x80\x60\x40\x10"

out = bytes((test[i]%16)*16 + test[i+1]//16 for i in range(len(test)-1))
print((out))
# b'P\x80`@\x10'
```

(As some values match the ASCII codes of printable characters, these characters are printed here instead of the `\x..` representation)